# How to find a string between two other strings with regex?

Tags: .net, regex

More or less obvious is :

```
\[start\](.*?)\[end\]
```

but that yields the [start] and [end] tag too.  How do you omit them?

E.g.: `f("[somestartstring]result[someendstring]") == "result"`

UPDATE: the suggested answers are not working. My code is:

```
printfn "%s" (Regex.Match(@"[start]result[end]",
                          "\\[start\\](.*?)\\[end\\]").Groups.[0].Value)
```

but it still yields the surrounding start and end tags.

My mistake is: the 0 index! Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this by regex? Just match `[start]whatever[end]`, and manually remove the first 7 and the last 5 characters, leaving `whatever`.

Comment: @pp indeed, i just found out tx

Comment: I downvoted, Peter, because I answered your question. Then you said "it's a .NET issue" so I provided .NET code. Then you said "it's not a syntax issue" and I was downvoted. Sigh. You try and help people and they are just short and sharp and dismissive.

Comment: @PP that is misuse for downvote, it has nothing to do with the question.  You hae downvoted me because you where downvoted and you can only downvote as reaction on the question, not as a kind of little revenge.

Comment: By the way the tag was indicating from the beginning it's a NET issue

Comment: @Joren : it's used as tool for html scraping. I use pattern matching and don't know beforehand what is before [start] or after [end]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a group, which is a match string within parantheses:

```
\[start\](.*?)\[end\]
```

These are numbered from 1 when you come to read them (zero being the whole matched string).  (There is also the facility of named groups if you find that more intuitive.)

E.g. in C#:

```
Match match = new Regex("\[start\](.*?)\[end\]").Match("[start]blah[end]");
string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: sounds very usefull, but in a test, i still yields the start and the endtag for me

Comment: test was this btw : 

printfn "%s" (Regex.Match(@"[start]result[end]", @"(?:\[start\])(.*?)(:?\[end\])").Groups.[0].Value)

which yields [start]result[end]

Comment: That is because you are looking at group 0 which is the whole string.  Instead use group 1 which is just the bit in the parantheses.

Comment: In fact, I am being stupid — you could just use groups.  I'll update my example.

Comment: (For posterity I initially suggested non-capturing groups (?:) but this is overkill for the specified problem.

Comment: Which is what I said in the beginning. Sigh.

Comment: Ah yes, so it is.  Have a vote.  Perhaps Peter will be kind enough to to change the accepted answer to yours?

Answer (score 3):

Remember `Groups[0]` matches the entire input. If you just want the first captured group it is `Groups[1]`, so

```
string text = "[start]blahblah[end]";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(text, @"\[start\](.*?)\[end\]").Groups[1].Value);
```

prints `blahblah`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\[start\](.*?)\[end\]`

C#

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\[start\\](.*?)\\[end\\]");
```

VB

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\[start\](.*?)\[end\]")
```

Comment: just removed the group capturing to 'start' and 'end'

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language. Usually you have to specify the matching group you want returned; often group zero is the whole matching expression, 1 is the first matching group, 2 is the second matching group, and so forth.

*Update 1*: please see http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

*Update 2*: Author seemed to think he understood .NET syntax. So removing code example and letting answer stand on its own.

Comment: see the .NET tag as for the library

Comment: I know the syntax. tx not the issue however

Comment: If the syntax isn't the issue, then what is the issue? You pointed out you were using .NET which seems pretty syntax-specific.

Comment: my problem was indeed the index, I apologize.  Calling me lazy however wasn't appropriate, neither is it to point out to google.  Just as I should have read the syntax better, you should read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: And since this anwer is less insulting and more useful, + 1,

Comment: I have flagged this answer for being called an idiot and lazy, (see edit remarks) This is not a direction i like SO to turn to

Comment: That aside : I admit that your first answer,apart from calling me lazy, was correct and I didn't see that. Maybe because when offended your concentrations isn't optimal. Sorry, you were right. But there's a difference between being right and being acknowledged for it, I have myselft experienced that many times on SO. I learned to live with it, it's inherent at communities that are formed by PEOPLE and (shockingly?) they make mistakes. But hopefully, they stay polite..

Comment: Agreed; completely inappropriate and unacceptable. @PP - I can't e-mail you privately since you don't have one listed - but note: that type of behaviour **will not** be tolerated; please keep it civil, or we will be forced to suspend your account.